# Attempting (and failing) to create user function for H2 database

Tags: java, mysql, h2

Our main database is MySQL.

Few queries are using fairly common `DATE_SUB($date, INTERVAL $duration $type)`.

We are running our tests over H2 database and the absence of `DATE_SUB()` function creates a problem.
We had an idea of creating a user H2 function to replicate MySQL behaviour - I had two separate attempts at that, both implementations existed and were mapped separately.

```
    CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS DATE_SUB FOR "xxx.yyy.Zzz.dateSubtract";

public Zzz {
        ...
        public static Date dateSubtract(Connection connection, String dateValue, String formula) {
            return dateSubtractJava(dateValue, formula);
        }

        public static Date dateSubtract(Connection connection, String dateValue, String INTERVAL, String numberOfDateIntervals, String dateIntervalName) {
            return dateSubtractJava(dateValue, INTERVAL, numberOfDateIntervals, dateIntervalName);
        }
        ...
}
```

unfortunately my attempts are failing with:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement 
...  
DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 1[*] DAY)  
expected "., (, [, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ), ,";
```

It looks like H2 is NOT even attempting to use my user function but failing while trying to parse the SQL statement.

Did anybody manage to do something like that successfully?

Comment: Did you test the function from command line? If so, did you test it with the `[*]` in there (or did the parser add this for you?)

Comment: Unfortunately, H2 does not support the interval data type, so `INTERVAL 1 DAY` is not understood.

Comment: The parser added the `[*]` where the syntax error occurred.

Comment: @ThomasMueller: Do I understand it correctly that due to H2 not recognising `INTERVAL` data type we can't do anything apart from using another function?

Comment: You would need to use a different data type instead of interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference and until H2 decides to add support for INTERVAL data type (it is in their to-do list)

It seems that at the moment the only option is to use alternative functionality:
at the moment

`TIMESTAMPADD(unquotedPeriodName, -1, :date)`

offers very similar functionality so that is what I will be using.